# Ball collision problems

Tags: math, 2d, collision, vector-graphics

So I have a system with colliding balls that generally works, except for when they collide with similar directions, less than 90 degrees apart.

[image: Diagram of colliding balls problem]

This is because the ball above tries to collide against the yellow line which is supposedly the collision plane, but it sends it off the wrong direction, and it "follows" the other ball. The general algorithm for the collision is:

```
dot = direction.surface;
parallel = surface * dot;
perpendicular = direction - parallel;
direction = perpendicular - parallel;
```

Which negates the component of the direction parallel to the surface normal, which is perpendicular to the collision plane, and the part perpendicular to the surface normal is unchanged.

Does anyone know a fix for this? Have I done something wrong?

Edit: So now I added:

```
average = (ball1.velocity + ball2.velocity) / 2;
ball1.velocity -= average;
ball2.velocity -= average;
```

Before doing the calculations above, and after that:

```
ball1.velocity += average;
ball2.velocity += average;
```

To get in the right reference frame, according to @Beta's answer. The problem now is that the speeds of the balls aren't maintained, since they both have the same speeds and masses, yet after the collisions they're different. I do not think this is supposed to happen, or is it?

Comment: This method is for use in the center-of-momentum frame. Does that clear things up, or should we explain more?

Comment: Do you mind explaining that a bit? There are so many examples online that use this method, yet it doesn't always work?

Comment: It's a long explanation. Are you familiar with the idea of changing reference frames?

Comment: Nope. Sorry I'm new to this. But now that I read a bit on it, do I basically have to change the origin of the coordinate system or something?

Comment: Wait... do you mean the other ball should collide against the vector perpendicular to the surface normal instead?

Comment: No, the problem is that *the surface is moving*. Suppose I'm on a jet plane in flight, and you're on the ground, and I toss a ball against the forward bulkhead and it bounces back at me. *In the reference frame of the ground* the ball is still moving forward at high speed, moving away from me but I am catching up. *In my reference frame* I am standing still and the ball is moving backward, toward me. The idea that ball reversed direction makes sense in my reference frame, but it's not true in yours. If this is unfamiliar to you, we should start with 1D collisions and work up.

Comment: Oh yes, I am familiar with that. I'm just not completely sure how it applies mathematically to my case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the 1D problem of bouncing a ball off a wall. Simple.

Now watch me bounce a ball off the forward bulkhead of a jet plane in flight. The ball is moving north at 252 m/s, the bulkhead is moving north at 250 m/s. The answer is not obvious. But shift into my coordinate frame (by subtracting the velocity of the bulkhead, 250 m/s, from everything) and the problem is trivial. Solve it, then shift the result back into the ground frame (by *adding* 250 m/s to everything) and you're done.

Now the 2D problem of a ball bouncing off a wall at an angle. Simple. (But verify that your code does it correctly.)

Now two balls colliding with equal and opposite momenta (I'll assume they have the same mass, for now). You can imagine a yellow wall at the collision plane, and the answer comes easily.

Now two balls colliding, but with velocities that do *not* add up to zero. There's still a yellow wall, but it's moving. Well, shift into the wall's frame by subtracting the average of the balls' velocities (sum/2) from everything, solve the simpler problem, then shift back by adding that same velocity back to everything, and you're done.

Comment: Good, thanks. Only one question: if both balls have the same speed, their speeds will be the same after the collision too, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. Using the center-of-momentum frame is a great technique, it saves us from a lot of cryptic algebra. Don't try to take a further shortcut until you're really comfortable with this technique.

Comment: But the way I've currently set it up is that it has a direction unit vector and a speed variable, and I perform the collision physics only on the direction vector. That's why it would be nice if they always had the same speed, so the direction vector is always a unit vector...