# Circular collision rebound not working properly

Tags: c++

I'm writing a little physics simulation in C++ that basically moves circles across the screen and when two circles collide, they should ricochet in the same manner as billiard balls would. When the circles do collide with each other, most of the time they will practically slow down infinitely/they appear to stick to each other and become static. Sometimes only one ball will rebound in the collision and the other will retain it's trajectory. This is just a simple 2D simulation.

So here's what I have for the detection/ricochet logic:

```
bool Ball::BallCollision(Ball &b2)
{
    if (sqrt(pow(b2.x - x, 2) + pow(b2.y - y, 2)) <= b2.radius + radius) // Test for collision
    {
        normal[0] = (x - (x + b2.x) / 2) / radius; // Finds normal vector from point of collision to radius
        normal[1] = (y - (y + b2.y) / 2) / radius;
        xvel = xvel - 2 * (xvel * normal[0]) * normal[0]; // Sets the velocity vector to the reflection vector
        yvel = yvel - 2 * (yvel * normal[1]) * normal[1];

        ////x = xprev; // These just move the circle back a 'frame' so the collision
        ////y = yprev; // detection doesn't detect collision more than once.
                   // Not sure if working?
     }
}
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with my function. Thanks for any help in advance!

**Edit**:
Every variable is declared as a float

The functions:

```
void Ball::Move()
{
    xprev = x;
    yprev = y;
    x += xvel;
    y += yvel;
}

void Ball::DrawCircle()
{
    glColor3ub(100, 230, 150);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        angle = i * (2*3.1415/10);
        newx = x + r*cos(angle);
        newy = y + r*sin(angle);
        glVertex2f(newx, newy);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

The loop:

```
    run_prev.clear(); // A vector, cleared every loop, that holds the Ball objects that collided

    for (int i = 0; i < num_balls; i++)
    {
        b[i].Move();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_balls; i++)
    {
        b[i].WallCollision(); // Just wall collision detecting, that is working just fine
    }

    //The loop that checks for collisions... Am I executing this properly?
    for (int i = 0; i < num_balls; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < num_balls; j++)
        {
            if (i == j) continue;
            if (b[i].BallCollision(b[j]) == true)
            {
                run_prev.push_back(b[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_balls; i++)
    {
        b[i].DrawCircle();
    }

    //xprev and yprev are the x and y values of the frame before for each circle
    for (int i = 0; i < run_prev.size(); i++)
    {
        run_prev[i].x = run_prev[i].xprev;
        run_prev[i].y = run_prev[i].yprev;
    }
```

Comment: You should post what types your variables are, just to know if we can exclude rounding or other casting errors.

Comment: I don't understand why you calculate the normal like that. Are they supposed to have unit length?

Comment: I thought they were. Please correct me wherever I may have slipped up.

Comment: I just tried setting the normal to non unit length; it caused the balls to travel extremely fast, so I'm not sure if that is my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Makes balls collide (reflect movement vector) **only if they're moving towards each other**. Do not process collision if they're moving away from each other. Break this rule, and they'll be glued together.
2. When processing collision, update both balls at once. Do not update one ball at a time.
3. Your move vector adjustment is incorrect. Balls don't reflect against each other, because they can be moving at different speeds.

Correct movement adjustment (assuming balls have equal mass) should look something like that:

```
pos1 and pos2 = positions;
v1 and v2 are movement vector (speed);
n is collision normal == normalize(pos1 - pos2);
collisionSpeed = dot((v2-v1), n);
collisionSpeed *= elasticy; (0.0..1.0);
v1 = v1 - dot(v1, n);
v2 = v2 - dot(v2, n);
v1 -= scale(n, collisionSpeed * 0.5);
v2 += scale(n, collisionSpeed * 0.5);
```

To understand the formula, check newtons law (impulses in particular). Or check Chris Hecker's papers on game physics.

Comment: Thanks. How do you test if they're moving towards each other?

Comment: @vorbis5: in the example above check the sign of collisionSpeed.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you're calling this function, but I think I see the problem.

Say you have `Ball ballA` and `Ball ballB`, which are colliding in the current frame, and then you run `ballA.BallCollision(ballB)`.

This will update the member variables of `ballA`, and move it back a frame. But it doesn't update the position or trajectory of `ballB`.

Even if you call the converse as well (`ballB.BallCollision(ballA)`), it won't detect the collision because when you called `ballA.BallCollision(ballB)`, it moved ballA back a frame.

Comment: Very good insight, I'll edit my code a bit and see if that solves my problem!

Comment: Hmm, the problem still exists. When a slow circle collides with another, they both just stick together and quit moving, and the rebounding itself seems a little off or something. It's weird, I posted more of my code up top and maybe you can take another look at it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at your code in detail, but it doesn't take into consideration that this type of collision can only work in center of momentum frames. Now, I assume your balls are of equal masses. What you do is take the average of the two momentums (or velocities since they have the same masses) and subtract that average from the velocities. Perform your calculations, and add the average back. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509602/ball-collision-problems) is the question I asked that may relate to this.

Comment: Alright, I tried that, and now the balls are still sticking and clumping together, but at least when they collide and stick they don't become static. I think my main issue here is the sticking of the balls when they collide.

Comment: Do you have code that moves the balls away from each other enough so the don't intersect anymore? And I'm not totally sure about the way you calculate your normals...

Comment: All my code is pretty much up there. i thought if each ball's position was stored before they moved, and then tested for collision, that if they collided I would just set there previously stored positions as there new positions, like moving them back a frame. What is wrong with my normals?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is quite old, but it's still relevant, especially to students. Something that wasn't mentioned in the answers made me want to contribute.

One thing that I ran into when solving a similar problem was *overlap*.  That is, if the moving balls overlap by any amount at all, the collision detection will trigger continuously, giving the sticking behavior the OP referred to.

There was an attempt here to prevent this by moving the balls to the previous frame, but that can occasionally fail if the movement was enough that the balls enmeshed more than a single frame can account for, or if the movement velocity is just right so that the frame before doesn't trigger collision but the frame after is too far overlapped.

Since the original check was for center distance less than or equal to the sum of the radii, the detection triggers on both collision AND overlap.
One way to fix this is to separate the test into checking for collision (equals only) or overlap (less than only). For the collision, proceed as normal. But for the overlap condition, you can physically move one ball or the other (or both by half) the amount of overlap. This positions them at correct "collision" position, which allows for the correct behavior of the bounce function.

An overlap function that only moves one ball at a time might look something like this(not real code):

```
    if (distanceBetweenBallCenters < sumOfRadii){
       currentPosition = oldPosition - (distanceBetweenBallCenters - sumOfRadii) * (unitVectorFromSecondBallToFirstBall);
    }
```

One could easily move both balls by half, but I found that moving one at a time gave satisfactory results for my uses, and allowed me to keep the parameter as a const.

I hope this helps future students! (I am also a student, and new to this, so take my advice with the proverbial grain of salt)

Answer (score 0):

Your way of calculating the normal is wrong. (x + b2.x)/2 doesn't have to be the point of collision, if the radii of the balls aren't equal.

Comment: The way I have setup my simulation thus far is that all the radii equal.